# How to authorize remote user to passRole to generated role in SAM lambda deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I want to deploy a lambda function with SAM. For that I need to assign policies to `LocalDeveloper`, the user who is deploying from their machine. I've already assigned some permissions to the user and now I get `Resource handler returned message: "User: arn:aws:iam::0123456789:user/LocalDeveloper is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::0123456789:role/<stack name>-<lambda name>-<hash> (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 403, Request ID: 4111d938-73af-41af-a2a8-d0cd3ca9e60c, Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: 85dca9d2-09e7-a9a6-9711-31d9fb6397d6, HandlerErrorCode: AccessDenied)`

There is an easy fix for that: just add

```
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::0123456789:role/<stack-name>*"]
        }
```

to `LocalDeveloper`'s existing policies. However AWS gives me a security warning¹:

```
PassRole With Star In Resource: Using the iam:PassRole action with wildcards (*) in the resource can be overly permissive because it allows iam:PassRole permissions on multiple resources. We recommend that you specify resource ARNs or add the iam:PassedToService condition key to your statement
```

With a link to [the User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access-analyzer-reference-policy-checks.html#access-analyzer-reference-policy-checks-security-warning-pass-role-with-star-in-resource)

I get the gist of it: the policy allows any role to be assigned to any role that starts with `<stack-name>`. I know I cannot specify the resource ARN because it is only known at compile time. That leaves me with `add the iam:PassedToService condition key to your statement` I would need to extend the policy to

```
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "iam:PassRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::0123456789:role/<stack-name>*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "iam:PassedToService": "arn:aws:iam::0123456789:role/<stack-name>*"
            }
        }
```

Or something like it. But the above does not resolve the security warning (and I don't think I can use a role for `iam:PassedToService`).
How can I get properly resolve this security warning?

¹ The security warning only appears because in my case `<stack-name>` is shorter than 6 characters, and that is because I used a prefix that several stacks have in common.

Comment: Is it just a warning, that you can ignore if you desire? If so, feel free to ignore it. The warning is to prevent people granting `*` on PassRole, but your inclusion of Stack Name is much safer.